# Is `seek` reliable on modern Windows?

Tags: r, windows, winapi

From [manual page](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/seek) for `seek` in R:

> Use of seek on Windows is discouraged. We have found so many errors in
>   the Windows implementation of file positioning that users are advised
>   to use it only at their own risk, and asked not to waste the R
>   developers' time with bug reports on Windows' deficiencies.

Is this still true for modern versions of Windows with NTFS file system?

Comment: You're asking some good R+Windows questions but you might get better answers if you join the [r-devel mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) as the R developers do engage in constructive dialog (take a look at the archives and/or [r-devel bugzilla](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/)) and some of the rationale for various behavior is explained there.

Comment: @hrbrmstr The quote in the question doesn't seem very constructive. Nor does it seem to encourage R users to engage with the R developers. Quite the opposite. Talking to the R developers, as you suggest, can't be a bad thing to do. Asking in Windows tags on SO is also a good idea.

Comment: Everyone is entitled to their opinion @DavidHeffernan. I've indicated similar about your engagement with the R community on SO today (in terms of being both constructive and congenial).

Comment: @hrbrmstr If anyone can show that Windows has ever had problems with file seeking and truncating then your points would be valid. Otherwise I don't think that calling me a troll is really very constructive or congenial.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: I don't know, what good questions you are referring to. This question, however, is certainly not a good one, in the same way that any other question of the form *"<false statement>: Is this still true?"* is a good question. This question is not even formally ok. If you are referencing off-site information, that is vital to the question, you should at least provide a link for reference. If you believe this question has potential, feel free to improve it (by adding a link, and explaining those *Windows deficiencies*).

Comment: @IInspectable Link added. I have no idea about the specific Windows deficiencies. Would like to know, too.

Comment: @qed What deficiencies? IInspectable knows there aren't any. He's just calling out hrbrmstr.

Answer (score 9):

> Is this still true for modern versions of Windows with NTFS file system?

This not true, and has never been true. File seeking on Windows has always been implemented correctly.

Clearly the person who wrote the quote in your question has been unable to fix the defects in their own code and decided instead to believe that Windows is defective. This is known as *software development by wishful thinking*.

Comment: you aren't even going through the trouble of simple google searches or—heaven forbid—reviewing the r-devel bug reporting system before pontificating.

Answer (score 3):

This is such a stupid claim that I had to google it. Of course, it is bogus, and is due to incorrect assumptions in usage. Here is just one link that addresses the claim: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-January/424889.html.